# Why does declaring a manager to a Django model, void "objects"

Tags: django, django-managers

I have declared a manager to the following model, but after doing so, I can no longer use `List.objects.get()`. Anybody know why?

```
class List(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
  archived = models.BooleanField()

  archived_lists = ArchivedListManager()
  active_lists = ActiveListManager()
```

And the managers:

```
class ArchivedListManager(models.Manager):
  def get_query_set(self):
    return super(ArchivedListManager, self).get_query_set().filter(archived=True)

class ActiveListManager(models.Manager):
  def get_query_set(self):
    return super(ActiveListManager, self).get_query_set().filter(archived=False)
```

The error is `type object 'List' has no attribute 'objects'`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As noted in the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/managers/#topics-db-managers):

> If you use custom `Manager` objects, take note that the first `Manager` Django encounters (in the order in which they're defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first `Manager` defined in a class as the "default" `Manager`, and several parts of Django will use that `Manager` exclusively for that model. As a result, it's a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding `get_query_set()` results in an inability to retrieve objects you'd like to work with.

So as far as "why" goes, it's to allow you to provide your own default manager.

The solution is simple, though: just add this

```
objects = models.Manager()
```

to your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding your own manager suppresses creation of the stock manager.

["Manager names"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-names)

Comment: I made this manager "class ListManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ListManager, self).get_query_set()" which prints the correct objects with List.objects, but it fails with "List.objects.get(example=example) How can I fix that?

Comment: That sounds like a completely separate question.